# How do I match up Adobe's color profile to Apple's?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs6, color-profile

Why is there such a difference in the editing view & save preview views? I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6 for Mac OS X.

**Color Settings:** North America General Purpose 2

**Profile:** sRGB

**Export Format:** PNG-24

[image: CMYK Color Mode]

[image: RGB Color Mode]

Comment: could you please tell us a bit more about the settings you're using, color profiles, file format of your export etc.? As-is, your question is very hard to answer and could very well be put on hold because it's 'unclear what you're asking'. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the color settings are North America General Purpose 2. The profile is sRGB. File format is PNG-24. Sorry for the lack of information, if I need to include more let me know.

Comment: @Bakabaka see above

Comment: What version of Photoshop is that? I'd assume CC due to the dark UI, but I have more options in the Save for Web dialog than your images show -- specifically color setting/profile options.

Comment: @Scott It's actually Illustrator CS6. I know I should of included all of this stuff now, sorry guys.

Comment: Yeah it just now dawned on me that it's Illustrator.

Comment: Have you calibrated your monitor? What's your working RGB setting? The color engine? Basically, the color settings in Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott Yes i have calibrated my monitor, but that shouldn't make the edit/preview color different should it? Current settings: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LDWsGCZ.png)

Comment: Click the "More Options" in the color settings.. what's there? If not set.. try Adobe (ACE) and Relative Colormetric and tick BlackPoint Compensation. -- And yes monitor calibration can effect a great deal.

Comment: @Scott what you suggested is exactly what appears when I click "More Options." I realize the monitor settings effect the monitor color, but if you don't mind explaining, how would it effect the color of the editing/saving views when I am viewing them on the same monitor? Feel free to send me a link, and thank you for your help so far.

Comment: This question relates: When I export an image from Illustrator, why is it a slightly different color in the exported image? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/6373/3901

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like to me, is one of two things...

1. you are saving to png(an RGB format), from a CMYK file

**Solve:**
Under file, check your document color mode and make sure it's set to RGB, illustrator defaults to CMYK for print and you should be able to change that in your preferences if you want.

or

2. you are viewing some proof color mode

**Solve:**
Under view, make sure proof colors is unchecked, or under view you can go into proof setup and select sRGB as your proof setup, and that should match your color space.

**Additional Notes:**
You might also want to open your color palette and make sure that is set to RGB in the options menu at the far right of the palette.